# what google sheets regex formula will split thai text of variable lengths into different cells but with flexible conditions

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split

I am trying to find a regex expression for the google sheets formula regexreplace to divide the following Thai text so that it is in easier to manage ie in separate cells to translate using google translate formula.

(note this text is a mix and match to show the type of lengths i need to deal with ie it does not necessarily make sense!)

Some of the text is long (multiple words together and that is fine and can stay that way. But some is very short just 3, 4 or 5 characters and i do not want to break them up if they are too short ie combine short words into a single cell - just not too long!

**Key Critera**
so if the text is continuous and over say 15 characters then it is to be placed in one cell. if it a few small words say 3 to 5 letter words separated by spaces then they can be joined but that should be limited to say up 20 characters. if there is a full stop then don't include words after the full stop in the same cell even if they would not add up to 20 characters.

thankyou in advance for any help/suggestions

```
กถามรรคที่เล่าเรื่องตั้งแต่ พระมหาสัตว์ได้ตั้งปรารถนาอย่างจริงจัง ณ เบื้องบาทมูลของพระพุทธเจ้าทรงพระนามว่า ทีปังกร จนถึงจุติจากอัตภาพเป็นพระเวสสันดร แล้วไปเกิดในสวรรค์ชั้นดุสิต จัดเป็น ทูเรนิทาน.
บทว่า ขณนฺตา แปลว่า ขุดภาคพื้น.
ศัพท์ว่า อุท ในบทว่า อุทงฺคเณ นี้ เป็นนิบาต อธิบายว่า ในที่ลานกลางแจ้ง.
```

to become

```
กถามรรคที่เล่าเรื่องตั้งแต่
พระมหาสัตว์ได้ตั้งปรารถนาอย่างจริงจัง ณ
เบื้องบาทมูลของพระพุทธเจ้าทรงพระนามว่า 
ทีปังกร (because the preceding and following text (word/s) are long (ie without any white space)
จนถึงจุติจากอัตภาพเป็นพระเวสสันดร 
แล้วไปเกิดในสวรรค์ชั้นดุสิต 
จัดเป็น ทูเรนิทาน.
ศัพท์ว่า อุท ในบทว่า 
อุทงฺคเณ นี้ เป็นนิบาต 
อธิบายว่า ในที่ลานกลางแจ้ง.
```

I have been using the different AI bots to help and trying to modify them but not luck...
(i also add split, transpose or flatten to place it into separate cells / rows- but that part seems to be fine, although i have tried to use `char(10)` as well with no luck)

maybe i am trying to get a regex to do too much. maybe i need to somehow use a count function before applying a different regex formula...

(note i you will see various number parameters eg 14, 99, 4 etc...tried using some different numbers in the expressions to try to see if they produce better results)

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(G2,"(.{1,20})(\s+|$|\.)", "♦$1"), "♦"))
```

this cuts off words before it gets to a white space. I only wish for it to cut off when it arrives at a white space, full stop or end of line. It cannot cut off in the middle of a word.

```
=FLATTEN(split(REGEXREPLACE(G2,"((\S+\s+){1,4}\S.{14,99})(\s+|$)","$1 ^^^"),"$1 ^^^"))
```

this just picks up each individual word based on spaces. so some are too short.

```
=TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE(G1, "({\w{1,2}\s+}|[^\s]{4,444})","$1"))
```

picks up each word without allowing them to be longer.

truly appreciate any feedback

Comment: sorry about the bold. dont know what happened there and the edit function doesnt seem to allow for removing text bolding.